# Как передать параметр и знак процента (%) в SQL. Пример: [col_name LIKE "?%"]

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Помогите исправить ошибку в запросе.

Строка:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Погода WHERE name LIKE "?%" ORDER BY name, country', (name, ))
```

Ошибка:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Погода WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY name, country', (name + '%',))`

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к [методу, показанному @andreymal в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806435/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-sqlite3/806446#comment1276410_806435), можно воспользоваться конкатенацией (объединением) строк:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Погода WHERE name LIKE ? || '%' ORDER BY name, country", (name, ))
```

Тест:

```
In [20]: cursor.execute("select * from aaa where s like ? || '%'", ('aa',))
Out[20]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x2cbe2550f80>

In [21]: cursor.fetchall()
Out[21]: [('aaaa',), ('aaab',), ('aabb',)]
```

PS [несмотря на то что оператор конкатенации строк `||` является ANSI SQL Standard, он не поддерживается такими популярными СУБД как `MySQL` и `MS SQL Server`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/String_functions) - в этих СУБД можно воспользоваться функцией [`CONCAT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)